# How to add multiple question to a variable in AMOS?

Tags: path-model, amos

My questions is from  path analysis.

I have a model with 11 variables (DTPB: Decomposed Theory of Planned Behavior), and I publish questionnaire with likert-scale (1 to 5). Each of this 11 variables have 2, 3 or 4 questions in my questionnaire.

I draw my model in AMOS, but i don`t know how to connect these questions to their variables.

Comment: Are you saying that you have 11 latent variables and 2 to 4 observed variables per latent variable?

Answer (score 1):

As I discuss [here on Slide 17](http://web.psych.unimelb.edu.au/jkanglim/IntroductiontoSEM.pdf), you would usually use the elipse drawing tools to draw the latent factors and then add observed variables using the the tool represented by the following icon:

[image: amos button]

You can then drag and drop the observed questions into the boxes.